# Column data randomly missing on oracle

Tags: java, oracle, weblogic

I have the following query (the three dots are the name of other fields not relevant to the question):

```
select ..., b.vpan, from a left outer join b on a.pan=b.pan where a.pan like '%'
```

This works fine when I run it on the SQLDeveloper but in my application this isn't the case.

I have developed a webapp that is deployed on Weblogic 12c and sometimes this query is missing the value for the **VPAN** field.

I'm using the same JDBC version on SQLDeveloper and Weblogic and I have enabled JDBC logging and I saw that indeed this field value is missing on the JDBC logs.

I'm really not to sure how to procedure from here so any input will be helpful.

Thanks

Comment: "sometimes this query is missing the value for the `VPAN` field." What does this mean? Do you get an error? If so, what is the error message? Is the value `NULL`? If so, should it be `NULL` and is the application correctly handling the value? Please [edit] your question to include a [MRE] including some sample data which demonstrates the issue and a minimal example of your code so that we can replicate the issue and aren't just guessing.

Comment: Try adding `and b.vpan is null` to your query in SQL Developer to view only the rows missing VPAN values.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce the problem as well. This only happens on the PROD environment of the client. No error. The value is NULL.

Comment: If you can't reproduce the problem there's no chance we're going to be able to help you. It's probably data related but who can tell?

Comment: @APC I just need some ideas to what to do next.

Comment: @rcv91592 Do you have any database redaction policies that might blank out values for certain users?

Comment: You are also using a left outer join on a.pan=b.pan. When there is no matching b.pan for a given a.pan then the column b.vpan will be null.